# Add swf to canvas

Tags: flash, canvas

I'm trying to add the following swf: http://assets.zwinky.com/assets3/stud/express/01/ex1.2.swf to a canvas.

```
<canvas style="position: relative; display: block; width: 100%;" width="565" height="656" src="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets3/stud/express/01/ex1.2.swf"></canvas>
```

How could I preview this now? The only way I got the canvas showing was:

```
<object width="100" height="100">
    <param name="movie" value="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets3/stud/express/01/ex1.2.swf">
    <embed src="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets3/stud/express/01/ex1.2.swf" width="100" height="100">
    </embed>
</object>
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use native html5 canvas to do your flapping wings effect.

**The Parts**

To rotate a wing around its wing root:

- `context.translate` to the point on the canvas where you want the wing root to be. `translate` causes the canvas origin [x=0,y=0] to be moved to your translation point.
- `context.rotate` to your currently desired wing flap angle
- `context.drawImage` to draw your wing image. You must draw your wing offset by the position of the wing root in the original image. This offset pulls the wing root to the newly translated canvas origin.

To animate the flapping:

`requestAnimationFrame` gives you an efficient animation loop that fires about every 1/60th second.

In the animation loop:

- Draw the wings at the current `flapAngle`
- Change the `flapAngle` for the next animation loop
- request another loop through the animation. requestAnimationFrame calls a function just once, so when the current animation loop is complete, you must call `requestAnimationFrame` again to request the next loop.

**Here's annotated code and a Demo:**

```js
// canvas vars
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// wing vars
var leftwing,rightwing;         // the wing canvas-images
var lx=230;                     // X of left wing root
var ly=117;                     // Y of left wing root
var rx=7;                       // X of right wing root
var ry=117;                     // Y of right wing root
var wingPadding=40;             // controls space between wings

// animation vars
var flapAngle=0;                // controls current flap angle
var flapIncrement=Math.PI/240;  // controls animation speed
var flapDirection=1;            // controls flap direction
var minFlapAngle=-Math.PI/8;    // controls max upflap
var maxFlapAngle=Math.PI/30;    // controls max downflap

// load the wing image
var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/wings.png";
function start(){
    // make left & right canvas-wings
    makeWings();
    // start the animation
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function animate(time){
    // flap the wings at the current flapAngle
    flapWings(300,150,flapAngle);
    // change the flapAngle for next animation loop
    flapAngle+=flapIncrement*flapDirection;
    if(flapAngle>maxFlapAngle || flapAngle<minFlapAngle){
        flapDirection*=-1;
        flapAngle+=flapIncrement*flapDirection;
    }
    // request another animation loop
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function makeWings(){
    // clip left wing from the img
    leftwing=document.createElement('canvas');
    var cctx=leftwing.getContext('2d');
    leftwing.width=237;
    leftwing.height=130;
    cctx.drawImage(img,26,26,237,130,0,0,237,130);
    // make right wing as mirror image of left wing
    rightwing=document.createElement('canvas');
    cctx=rightwing.getContext('2d');
    rightwing.width=237;
    rightwing.height=130;
    cctx.translate(237,0);
    cctx.scale(-1,1);
    cctx.drawImage(leftwing,0,0);
}

function flapWings(x,y,rAngle){
    // clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

    // LEFT wing
    // move the canvas origin to the coordinate where
    //     you want the left wing root to be 
    ctx.translate(x,y);
    // rotate the canvas by the current flapAngle
    ctx.rotate(rAngle);
    // draw the left wing on the canvas
    ctx.drawImage(leftwing,-lx,-ly);
    // always clean up -- reset transformation back to default
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);

    // RIGHT wing
    // move the canvas origin to the coordinate where
    //     you want the left wing root to be 
    ctx.translate(x+wingPadding,y);
    // rotate the canvas by the current flapAngle
    ctx.rotate(-rAngle);
    // draw the right wing on the canvas
    ctx.drawImage(rightwing,-rx,-ry);
    // always clean up -- reset transformation back to default
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=650 height=300></canvas>
```